# Call previous layout on Android device?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I call previous layout when I click `back` button on a tablet or phone?

I want to call previous layout, but When I click the `back` button on tablet, the app completely shuts down. Then I need to reopen the app. Why is that happening?

My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button girisyap_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    girisyap_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_gonder);

    girisyap_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            setContentView(R.layout.giris_ekrani);


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you are loading your second layout?

Comment: `Back` button never loads the previous layout, it switches back to the previous activity (if available). You need to override it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are loading another view in the same activity. Hence you need to override Back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // load previous layout here
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

@Override

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

       onBackPressed();


    }
```